# why the "?>" tag won't close the php part?

Tags: php

So I was writing some PHP scripts and also some HTML codes but this was what happened:

```
<?php
/*
some php scripts
*/
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1' AND username='test' AND pass='123'; /* the last line of php */
?>
```

this was the last code that I used and after that I closed the php and started the html part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

so at this point when I check localhost and my database I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'utf' (T_STRING) in F:\wamp64\www\Login2.php on line 47

and it's because of the HTML code I used. although I closed the PHP with ?> it's still counting HTML codes as PHP!

Comment: you are missing a closing `"`

Comment: Count the number of double-quotes in your code.

Comment: Use an IDE/editor with syntax highlighting. (They're free.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is not closed with " that is why you get an error

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1 AND username='test' AND pass='123'";
```

it should be like above.

Comment: Simple typos do not need an answer as they are of limited value to future researchers.  The question has been closed as a simple typo.

Comment: what is simple for one may be difficult for the other :)

Comment: Others seem to have pointed to the error using a comment and the question may be deleted anyway so any rep earned is wasted.

Comment: I don't really care for rep :) I have 14k already. It may be removed but still I'm happy cause it helped someone. Cheers.